# http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client in Golang httptest

Tags: http, go, https

I got http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client in Golang httptest, when testing a get request of https url using httptest server below.
It works fine when I use URL start with "http://"

```
func testingHTTPClient(handler http.Handler) (*http.Client, func()) {
    s := httptest.NewServer(handler)

    cli := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: func(_ context.Context, network, _ string) (net.Conn, error) {
                return net.Dial(network, s.Listener.Addr().String())
            },
        },
    }

    return cli, s.Close
}
```

refer from
[Code snippet](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/romanyx/6aaccbab51467f2b3a177b14419ebbbf/raw/80609c36f0b692b485b49f5897c4089a2252968a/test_client.go)

[How to stub requests to remote hosts with Go](https://itnext.io/how-to-stub-requests-to-remote-hosts-with-go-6c2c1db32bf2)

Comment: Use [Server.Client](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server.Client) instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that instead of

`s := httptest.NewServer(handler)`,

I should use

`s := httptest.NewTLSServer(handler)`

to get a https server.